# How to add Ad Hoc database content to Textfield

Tags: jasper-reports

I have an input parameter which is an ID.

I want to use a lookup table in the database to expand that ID into a long name for use in the report title.

How could I just add text into a textfield from a SQL query without needing to worry about rows of tabular data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *List* component in the *Title* band. This *List* (or *Table* component) will be associated with another additional (non main) datasource for showing information (the Name by Id passed via Parameter in your case).

The main datasource will be used by *Detail* band (or another *Table* component with the its own datasource) for showing data filtered by parameter's value (Id in your case).

With help of *textField*'s property *isStretchWithOverflow* (with **true** value) we can garantee that all text will be drawing with the *textField*.

### The sample

In this sample I've used the DB distributed with the *Jaspersoft Studio*. The parameter *addrId* was used for filtering data by the *id* field of *address* table. This parameter was mapped to the *List*'s datasource parameter with the same name (*addrId*). Yes, I've used the *List* component placed on *Title* band for showing information about the value of our external parameter (the city and the street of address in this sample). At the *Detail* band we are showing the information about documents (table *document*) related to our address (defined by *addrId*)

#### The report's template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="growing_text" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="77f0cb04-7f4b-43dc-af12-89c25fa7c58c">
    <subDataset name="dsAddrTitle" uuid="0eb7cd0c-f4f1-408d-be13-dc484fda80d5">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
        <parameter name="addrId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT city + ', ' + street AS name FROM address WHERE id=$P{addrId}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="addrId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[33]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT ID, ADDRESSID, TOTAL FROM DOCUMENT WHERE  ADDRESSID=$P{addrId} ORDER BY ADDRESSID]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ADDRESSID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="TOTAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <title>
        <band height="10" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="160" y="0" width="40" height="10" uuid="f4cb4e5c-e2d7-4927-b143-4cfcd7d99b76"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" ignoreWidth="true">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="dsAddrTitle" uuid="4bf3eb57-f752-4856-ac3a-fd7e3a33f434">
                        <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                        <datasetParameter name="addrId">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{addrId}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="100">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="10" uuid="1b533c30-7868-450b-a5b9-59d5130dcb67"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="100faa3b-790d-4dc6-b86c-8911a8762207"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="185" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="aef6af65-f7b5-42e9-a102-aeb272f99103"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ADDRESSID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="2c176a21-6387-4505-836e-7e250751755f"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="22cbe96d-5322-40e3-bd96-d2aa9bf35dd2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="185" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="3adedcc9-f60e-4664-bbe8-6b7d7b8e13a4"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESSID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00#">
                <reportElement x="370" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="48041fd6-1375-4819-8ebb-ffd4aef84889"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The output result

[image: The result via preview in Studio]