# Retrieve second result from query with parameter in JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have code for JasperReport:

```
        int id = 1;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM invoices where id = '"+ id + "'";
        InputStream source = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("tre/"+ reportName + ".jrxml");
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(source);
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jd.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, ConnectionToDb.connectDb());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
```

So far so good. This bring me in the report exactly number of rows for current invoice. Now how I can add Fields in JasperReport, which will contains the detail info from both company for the invoice using SQL again and the query is come from java code in method?
Let's say this query:

```
        String company = textField.getText();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM companies where name = '"+ company + "'";
```

here is the part of JasperReport:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from invoices]]>
</queryString>
<field name="Name" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<field name="Type" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<field name="Quantity" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<field name="Price" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<field name="Info" class="java.lang.Object"/>
```

P.S. The query in the report I'm override it with `newQuery.setText(sql);`

Comment: The [How to add Ad Hoc database content to Textfield](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36019481/876298) post can help you

Comment: Good example, but still don't understand, how this comunicate with java? I'm using JavaSwing. When I get some value from the JFrame, this value to be parameter in the report for the query:
` <![CDATA[SELECT ID, ADDRESSID, TOTAL FROM DOCUMENT WHERE  ADDRESSID=$P{value} ORDER BY ADDRESSID]]>`

Comment: You can pass parameter to the report via parameters map. You are passing *null* instead of *Map*

Comment: Do you have *jrxml* file?

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I think now I understand. I just put the map - and now I can put variables in Report. It's work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
......          
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, param, ConnectionToDb.connectDb());
```

Then in JasperReport:
Parameters with pattern: `$P{nameCompany}`